# JMS Template close the connection before acknowledgement

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, jmstemplate

The application use JMS template to connect MQ. Post consumer read the message when it goes to acknowledge the error thrown below.

> com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC0020: This
> session is closed. An application called a method that must not be
> used after the session is closed. Ensure that the session is not
> closed before calling the method.

JMS Template Spring bean XML

```
<beans>
    <bean id="mqDestinationResolver"
          class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver">
    </bean>
    <bean id="QUEUE_CONNECTION_FACTORY" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory" >
        <property name="transportType" value="1" />
        <property name="queueManager" value="QM.XXX" />
        <property name="hostName" value="XXX.com" />
        <property name="port" value="XXX" />
        <property name="channel" value="XXX" />
        <property name="SSLCipherSuite" value="XXX" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="destination" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
        <constructor-arg value="INTERQUEUE" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="QUEUE_CONNECTION_FACTORY" />
        <property name="destinationResolver" ref="mqDestinationResolver"/>
        <property name="defaultDestination">
            <ref bean="destination" />
        </property>
        <property name="pubSubDomain" value="false"/>
        <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageConsumer" class="com.jms.JmsMessageConsumer">
        <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="jmsTemplate"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The JMS Consumer class.

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

public class JmsMessageConsumer {

private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

public JmsTemplate getJmsTemplate() {
    return jmsTemplate;
}

public void setJmsTemplate(JmsTemplate jmsTemplate) {
    this.jmsTemplate = jmsTemplate;
}

public Message receiveMessage() throws JMSException {
    System.out.println("Start  : Inside JMS message Consumer");
    Message msg =(Message)getJmsTemplate().receive();
    msg.acknowledge();
    System.out.println("End  : Inside JMS message Consumer");
    return msg;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session is already closed when the `receive()` exits. With `CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE`, the template automatically acks the message before exiting.

Comment: Is there any way where explicitly acknowledgement can be done?

Comment: Not using the `receive()` method - although you can run it in a transaction and throw an exception to roll it back. You can also drop down to the lower level JMS API using a `JmsTemplate.execute()` command.